# Unix "open ." not working because of libtiff?

Tags: macos, unix

I recently installed libtiff, since installing libtiff, "/usr/bin/open" no longer works and I am getting the following error. I have no idea how to fix this?

```
 dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_TIFFClientOpen
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libTIFF.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
 [1]    1184 trace trap  open .
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say with any certainty from the information given, but a not-too-wild guess is that libtiff was installed in such a way that various system components find the newly installed libtiff, rather than the system one that they expect (which is probably a completely different library that just happens to have the same name).

The obvious way to do that would be by modifying any of the multitude of environment variables that affect how the dynamic linker works (run 'man dyld' for details). Running 'env | grep DYLD_' should show you if this is the case. If there are such variables set, you will then have to figure out *where* they get set, and fix that.

As far as I can tell, any installation which relies on DYLD_* variables being set, system-wide, for routine operations, is broken, because it will very likely cause problems like this.